# How to find SharePoint documents by custom column value using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, rest, api, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online site via my Office 365 account, I've added a column - "CustomerId" to my documents. I want to find all documents with CustomerId of 102 in C# (not in JavaScript).

So far, I'm able to get all files under a folder

```
var files = graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[driveItemId]
            .Children.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Or see the same result in Graph Explorer
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{driveItemId}/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteId%7D/drive/items/%7BdriveItemId%7D/children)

but I haven't figured out the correct syntax to get all documents (driveIems) using the custom column filter condition in C# or in Graph Explorer. Examples of things I've tried:

In C#

```
var files = graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[driveItemId]
            .Search("fields/CustomerId eq 102").Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

In Graph Explorer
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{driveItemId}/search(q='CustomerId eq 102')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteId%7D/drive/items/%7BdriveItemId%7D/search(q='CustomerId%20eq%20102'))

Hope someone can help me out on this.

**Update:**
Previously I got the driveItemId from

```
var customerFolder = graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Root
    .ItemWithPath("CustomerGroup/IndustryGroup").Request().GetAsync().Result;
string driveItemId = customerFolder.Id;
```

I see I can get a ListItem

```
var customerFolder = graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Root
    .ItemWithPath("CustomerGroup/IndustryGroup").Request()
    .Expand(d => d.ListItem).GetAsync().Result;
```

but I only found a list ID of "4" from customerFolder.ListItem.Id

How shall I get a list ID so that I can use it in graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to utilize the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?filter=fields/CustomerId eq 123&expand=driveItem
```

Explanation:

- filter items in a list  via `filter` query option
- return associated drive items for a list item via `expand` query option

Here is an example for [`msgraph-sdk-dotnet`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet):

```
var request = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items.Request().Filter("fields/CustomerId eq 123").Expand(item => item.DriveItem).GetAsync();
foreach (var item in request)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.DriveItem.WebUrl);
}
```

**Update**

*The underlying document library list* (along with its properties)  for a drive could be retrieved like this:

```
var list = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.List.Request().GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine(list.Id);  //gives SharePoint List Id
```

> Note: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/drive`
>   endpoint returns *the default drive* (document library) for this site

**Reference**

[Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thank you Vadim. Can you check my updated question as I can't find a way to get a ListItemId?

Comment: Thanks again, Vadim. Your method does work! Is there some way to search/filter files only under a sharepoint folder (CustomerGroup/IndustryGroup)?

Comment: Instead of filtering, how would I simply return all custom columns and their values for each child item? By default they do not show, and `?expand=fields` didn't work for me.